# Normalisation from 1NF to 3NF

Tags: database-design, normalization

I need some guidance on normalisation from 1st Normal Form to 3rd Normal form. I have already set up my database which is working fine but needed to show some normalisation to show that I did do some design. MY only issue is that while going through the normal forms, have I actually normalised the database correctly or not?

Can somebody please have a look at my normalisation and show any changes I should make in their replies?

Screenshort of **ER schema** - For full size image click here:

[image: ER]

---

And where I started. Screenshot of **0NF**:

[image: 0NF]

---

Screenshot of **1NF**:

[image: 1NF]

---

Screenshot of **2NF**:

[image: 2NF]

---

Screenshot of **3NF**:

[image: 3NF]

Comment: Upload it to a web service like http://imgur.com/ and add the link here or in the question.

Comment: @carlbrooks I upvoted your question, so you con upload images :)

Comment: @ypercube I just deleted my comments so page looks cleaner

Comment: Hi, this is carl brooks, I just registered an account and as I already in Stack overflow, my points got carried into here which is cool. Anyway has anyone been tackling with this issue?

Comment: read up on Table Inheritance, it will make your life much easier. Student and Teacher and Admin should have the same parent type (Party), and they play different roles.

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan Appreciate what you are saying, But I have no time to make changes to database, got to hand in on Friday so I just need to do best with what I have got. My third normal form matches the current db tables and fields I have, but is the second and first normal form completly incorrect? If so can you show me what it should look like because I am running out of time.

Comment: carlbrooks can you try following the steps on this page? http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge

Comment: @jcolebrand I have reomved accounts, can I ask how to put this question into my account because this was written in guest account which I have now lost, this means I can't award answer as it is not in my actual account

Comment: Did you visit the link I provided above?

Comment: @jcolebrand Yeah I visited the link, I removed all the accounts and then click sow more login opions an then i just navigated me to the homepage. i want to be able to mark the answer soon so hoping I can get this question linked to my account so this can be achieved

Answer (score 1):

1. question.noofanswers.  Why is it there?  Cant you just pull this from answer table at run-time?  Or are you enforcing rules on this?
2. Your student table looks like it has transitive functional dependencies in it but I can't be sure.  Is year dependent on courseid?  At any rate you are likely to want to break off student records and what courses they take since a student could take multiple courses over time.

Those are the only clear normalization/Codd's rules issues I see with this.  I could be missing something though.

Expanding on the second.  Take your student table.  Presumably there is a natural key somewhere but for now let's use StudentEmail as a candidate key because this can uniquely identify a given student (if there is a practical problem in your case, you can use StudentID as a substitute for argument's sake).

In this case StudentForename, StudentSurname depend functionally on StudentEmail.  For every email address there is one and only one forename and surname associated with it.  You might want to break away StudentAlias as well because that would give you an ability to have more than one alias per student, but if you will not have that, it breaks no normalization rules.

The problem is that Year depends on (StudentEmail, CourseID) meaning you have a 2NF violation here, where some attributes are dependent on part of the candidate key and others are dependent on the whole candidate key.  This really needs to be fixed before you can call it 3NF.

Comment: Hi, noofanswers is there because we want to determine how many answers a question has so we know if the student has selected less, equal or more answers than the number of answers there are. If more answers selected then negative marking comes into play. Year is just which year the student is in the course e.g. first year student, 2nd year student etc. I did not know a student can take multiple courses at one time. If so I will mention in improvements coz running out of time. Other than what have you mentioned is the normalization ok?

Comment: Other than what I mentioned I don't see any issues with normalization.  Also you might want to keep historical data which is another reason for student to be broken off.  The year is a 3nf violation as far as I can tell.  Updating answer to explain why.

Comment: Also if noofanswers refers to the number of expected replies for a question that's perfectly legitimate and no normalization/codd's rules issues there.

Comment: @carlbrooks Just a minor suggestion: since table names can be quite long, you'd better name this table `numberofanswers`.

Comment: @ChrisTravers StudentAlias is suppose to be unique for each student, its full meaning is student number but university call it Alias. So each student belongs to an alias. It is possible that 2 students might have the same name so they are uniquely identified by alias

Comment: @ChrisTravers so I am trying to remember how it is written, if you are saying Year can be determined by a studentAlias (as that is unique) and course, then it 2NF should we seperate to state `StudentAlias, CourseId, Year`? Can they then be bought back together in `3NF` as I currently have it?

Comment: Ok, if it is something like a student number then it is functionally dependent and no normalization issues.  The way to think about this is to look back to algebra class and the definition of a function.  f(x) is a function of x if and only if for every value of x there is one value of f(x).  In that case we would say that f(x) is *functionally dependent* on x.  More on this below before I run out of space.

Comment: So in this case lets look at students and look for *natural candidate keys.*  I can see two possibilities.  These include StudentAlias and StudentEmail.  We can then say that StudentForename is a function of either of these candidate keys (necessarily).  CourseID is not necessarily functionally dependant on that key except for current course join purposes, but as soon as you store historical data it no longer is, so CourseID is not necessarily a function of StudentAlias or StudentEmail and so it should be broken off.

Comment: @ChrisTravers So from what I understand I should not include CourseId in Student Table but included a seperate table known as `Student_Course` for example and this will allow me to have student's take multiple courses and no normalisation issue with this?

Comment: @ChrisTravers Can you tell me what is the full algebra which relates to what you are saying with `f(x)`. Be very handy for my thesis. Actually if you know any other algebra/models which relates with the above then can you display them here and I will research them if you do not mind? I know my supervisor said to include models but i never really followed any models before

Comment: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/Alg/FunctionDefn.aspx is a good place to start.  Keep in mind it is a mere starting point and as soon as you have any continuity in a function your number of ordered pairs becomes infinite.

Comment: @ChrisTravers Thanks, i am trying to get this question which I made as guest linked to my main account so I can mark the answer